# How to add a copy of XML dynamically

Tags: java, android, xml, android-layout

I am making an Android app, and I want to copy some XML code in a Linear Layout, and re-insert it into the Linear Layout so that there are two of the Relative Layouts in the Linear Layout. I would like to do this dynamically by taking this code below:

```
 <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/tileContainerME"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical" >

        <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/tilesAreHERE"
        android:layout_width="207dp"
        android:layout_height="151dp" >

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/bottom1"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/top1"
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
            android:gravity="center_horizontal"
            android:text="1"
            />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/left1"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_centerVertical="true"
            android:gravity="center_vertical"
            android:text="2"
             />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/right1"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignBaseline="@+id/left1"
            android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/left1"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:gravity="center_vertical"
            android:text="3"
           />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/top1"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:gravity="center_horizontal"
            android:text="4"
             />

    </RelativeLayout>            
    </LinearLayout>
```

And then simply turning it into this:

```
 <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/tileContainerME"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical" >
        <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/tilesAreHERE"
        android:layout_width="207dp"
        android:layout_height="151dp" >

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/bottom1"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/top1"
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
            android:gravity="center_horizontal"
            android:text="1"
            />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/left1"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_centerVertical="true"
            android:gravity="center_vertical"
            android:text="2"
             />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/right1"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignBaseline="@+id/left1"
            android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/left1"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:gravity="center_vertical"
            android:text="3"
           />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/top1"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:gravity="center_horizontal"
            android:text="4"
             />

    </RelativeLayout>  

        <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/tilesAreHERE"
        android:layout_width="207dp"
        android:layout_height="151dp" >

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/bottom1"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/top1"
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
            android:gravity="center_horizontal"
            android:text="1"
            />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/left1"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_centerVertical="true"
            android:gravity="center_vertical"
            android:text="2"
             />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/right1"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignBaseline="@+id/left1"
            android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/left1"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:gravity="center_vertical"
            android:text="3"
           />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/top1"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:gravity="center_horizontal"
            android:text="4"
             />

    </RelativeLayout>                 
    </LinearLayout>
```

See how there would be TWO RelativeLayout sections... I would like to basically make a copy of one and then add it back in (I don't really know how many times I might have to do this in my program, that's why I am not literally inserting it into the XML, I would like to do it from the Java code).
This is what I have so far, but whenever I run it, the layout is wrong. What might be wrong with my code?

```
            LinearLayout m3 = (LinearLayout)findViewById(R.id.tileContainerME);
    RelativeLayout m = (RelativeLayout)findViewById(R.id.tilesAreHERE);     
    RelativeLayout m2 = new RelativeLayout(this);

    m2.setLayoutParams(m.getLayoutParams());
    m2.setGravity(m.getGravity());
    m2.setLayoutDirection(m.getLayoutDirection());


    TextView et1 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.bottom1);
    TextView et2 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.left1);
    TextView et3 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.right1);
    TextView et4 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.top1);

    TextView tv1 = new TextView(et1.getContext());
    TextView tv2 = new TextView(et2.getContext());
    TextView tv3 = new TextView(et3.getContext());
    TextView tv4 = new TextView(et4.getContext());

    tv1.setLayoutDirection(et1.getLayoutDirection());
    tv2.setLayoutDirection(et2.getLayoutDirection());
    tv3.setLayoutDirection(et3.getLayoutDirection());
    tv4.setLayoutDirection(et4.getLayoutDirection());

    tv1.setGravity(et1.getGravity());
    tv2.setGravity(et2.getGravity());
    tv3.setGravity(et3.getGravity());
    tv4.setGravity(et4.getGravity());

    tv1.setText(et1.getText());
    tv2.setText(et2.getText());
    tv3.setText(et3.getText());
    tv4.setText(et4.getText());

    m2.addView(tv4,et4.getLayoutParams());
    m2.addView(tv3,et3.getLayoutParams());
    m2.addView(tv2,et2.getLayoutParams());
    m2.addView(tv1,et1.getLayoutParams());  

    m3.addView(m2);
```

I don't see what's wrong with my code, any suggestions.....

THIS IS THE FULL XML DATA FILE:

```
         <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    tools:context=".MainActivity" >
  <HorizontalScrollView
        android:id="@+id/scrollHORIZON"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/linearLayout1" >



        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/tileContainerME"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="horizontal" >

            <RelativeLayout
            android:id="@+id/tilesAreHERE"
            android:layout_width="207dp"
            android:layout_height="151dp" >

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/bottom1"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/top1"
                android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
                android:gravity="center_horizontal"
                android:text="1"
                />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/left1"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
                android:layout_centerVertical="true"
                android:gravity="center_vertical"
                android:text="2"
                 />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/right1"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_alignBaseline="@+id/left1"
                android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/left1"
                android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
                android:gravity="center_vertical"
                android:text="3"
               />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/top1"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
                android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
                android:gravity="center_horizontal"
                android:text="4"
                 />

        </RelativeLayout>           
        </LinearLayout>


    </HorizontalScrollView>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Inflating the same layout inside it once again might help you achieve this.

Try this code:

```
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main_layout);

    LinearLayout main_layout = (LinearLayout)findViewById(R.id.tileContainerME);
    LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater)getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    LinearLayout child = (LinearLayout) inflater.inflate(R.layout.main_layout, null);
    main_layout.addView(child, 1);
}
```

You'll get something like this:

[image]

Comment: LogCat error:                        01-02 11:29:41.976: D/errorBad(1965): android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: Resource ID #0x7f08000a type #0x12 is not valid
It's not working.....

Comment: Why did you name the main_layout object after the actual layout? It doesn't make sense....

Comment: @littleHelper It worked for me and that's the reason I've shared the screen shot. You must have done some mistake in your xml file. Double check them. Otherwise, clean the project and then try running it again.

Comment: Don't worry, I got it to work! Thanks for the help! I'll mark your answer as correct!

Answer (score 0):

You are probably getting an error message that the `View` you are trying to add already has a parent. You would need to call `removeView()` on the parent of your `TextView`s or `removeAllViews()` to just remove them all before adding them to your new `RelativeLayout`. Something like

```
m.removeAllViews();

m2.addView(et1);
m2.addView(et2);
m2.addView(et3);
m2.addView(et4);
```

However, if you are adding them multiple times then you probably want to create new instances of them as you do with your `RelativeLayout` (`m2`). Then you can use the `params` that your original `TextView`s have. If this isn't your current error then please post your logcat but this will cause an exception.

**Edit**

```
TextView et1 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.top1);
TextView et2 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.right1);
TextView et3 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.left1);
TextView et4 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.bottom1);

//Create the new TextViews
TextView tv1 = new TextView(m.getContext());  //if inside Activity you can use this instead of m.getContext()
// set params which you can get from the above TextViews
m2.addView(tv1);
...
```

Comment: It works, but your code deletes the views that were there. I want to keep them, and insert the new set.... So that there are two sets...

Comment: Right, which is why I recommended not doing it this way. Instead, create new `TextViews` as you do with your `RelativeLayout`

Comment: See my edit. Just create new `TextView`s and add those.

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out!

```
   LinearLayout m3 = (LinearLayout)findViewById(R.id.tileContainerME);
    RelativeLayout m = (RelativeLayout)findViewById(R.id.tilesAreHERE);     
    RelativeLayout m2 = new RelativeLayout(m.getContext());

    m2.setLayoutParams(m.getLayoutParams());


    TextView et1 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.top1);
    TextView et2 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.right1);
    TextView et3 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.left1);
    TextView et4 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.bottom1);

    TextView tv1 = new TextView(et1.getContext());
    TextView tv2 = new TextView(et2.getContext());
    TextView tv3 = new TextView(et3.getContext());
    TextView tv4 = new TextView(et4.getContext());
    tv1.setText(et1.getText());
    tv2.setText(et2.getText());
    tv3.setText(et3.getText());
    tv4.setText(et4.getText());
    tv1.setLayoutParams(et1.getLayoutParams());
    tv2.setLayoutParams(et2.getLayoutParams());
    tv3.setLayoutParams(et3.getLayoutParams());
    tv4.setLayoutParams(et4.getLayoutParams());

    m2.addView(tv1);
    m2.addView(tv2);
    m2.addView(tv3);
    m2.addView(tv4);

    m3.addView(m2);
```

This will make a copy of the previous layout and then add it back into the current layout!

Comment: I'm glad you got it working but that's exactly what I told you to do in my answer.

Answer (score 0):

I FOR SURE got it working this time! I used this code:

```
 LinearLayout item = (LinearLayout)findViewById(R.id.tileContainerME);
        View child = getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.activity_main, null);
        item.addView(child);
```

It would copy the 'activity_main' class which holds solely the XML data for the tile. Then it copies it into the Horizontal Scroll View! Here is a screenshot of my solution:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/WxoJG.png